# Joomla afterLoad/afterRender slow

Tags: sql, performance, debugging, joomla

Im trying to debug a Joomla site on my local computer. I enabled default Joomla debug options and I see this on Profile Information tab:

```
Application 1.049 seconds (+1.049); 1.58 MB (+1.585) - afterLoad
Application 1.145 seconds (+0.096); 3.78 MB (+2.191) - afterInitialise
Application 1.463 seconds (+0.318); 6.75 MB (+2.976) - afterRoute
Application 1.535 seconds (+0.072); 7.79 MB (+1.035) - afterDispatch
Application 2.056 seconds (+0.521); 8.09 MB (+0.303) - beforeRenderModule mod_custom (footer-ES)
Application 2.079 seconds (+0.022); 8.12 MB (+0.027) - afterRenderModule mod_custom (footer-ES)
Application 2.079 seconds (+0.000); 8.12 MB (-0.002) - beforeRenderModule mod_dock (Dock de Aplicaciones Favoritas)
Application 2.199 seconds (+0.120); 9.85 MB (+1.733) - afterRenderModule mod_dock (Dock de Aplicaciones Favoritas)
Application 2.200 seconds (+0.000); 9.85 MB (+0.003) - beforeRenderModule mod_menu_acordeon (El centro)
Application 2.712 seconds (+0.512); 10.52 MB (+0.666) - afterRenderModule mod_menu_acordeon (El centro)
Application 2.712 seconds (+0.000); 10.52 MB (+0.007) - beforeRenderModule mod_menu_acordeon (Mi comunidad)
Application 2.963 seconds (+0.251); 10.55 MB (+0.021) - afterRenderModule mod_menu_acordeon (Mi comunidad)
Application 2.963 seconds (+0.000); 10.54 MB (-0.003) - beforeRenderModule mod_menu_acordeon (Mis alumnos)
Application 3.121 seconds (+0.157); 10.58 MB (+0.033) - afterRenderModule mod_menu_acordeon (Mis alumnos)
Application 3.121 seconds (+0.000); 10.57 MB (-0.003) - beforeRenderModule mod_menu_acordeon (Mi tutoría)
Application 3.245 seconds (+0.124); 10.59 MB (+0.012) - afterRenderModule mod_menu_acordeon (Mi tutoría)
Application 3.245 seconds (+0.000); 10.58 MB (-0.003) - beforeRenderModule mod_menu_acordeon (Incidencias)
Application 3.376 seconds (+0.132); 10.59 MB (+0.011) - afterRenderModule mod_menu_acordeon (Incidencias)
Application 3.377 seconds (+0.000); 10.59 MB (-0.003) - beforeRenderModule mod_menu_acordeon (Configuración)
Application 3.643 seconds (+0.266); 10.61 MB (+0.024) - afterRenderModule mod_menu_acordeon (Configuración)
Application 3.643 seconds (+0.000); 10.61 MB (-0.002) - beforeRenderModule mod_menu_acordeon (Informes)
Application 3.804 seconds (+0.161); 10.63 MB (+0.016) - afterRenderModule mod_menu_acordeon (Informes)
Application 3.805 seconds (+0.000); 10.62 MB (-0.004) - beforeRenderModule mod_courses (Mis cursos)
Application 4.070 seconds (+0.266); 10.91 MB (+0.285) - afterRenderModule mod_courses (Mis cursos)
Application 4.071 seconds (+0.000); 10.71 MB (-0.195) - beforeRenderModule mod_menu_acordeon (Aula)
Application 4.177 seconds (+0.106); 10.73 MB (+0.012) - afterRenderModule mod_menu_acordeon (Aula)
Application 4.177 seconds (+0.000); 10.72 MB (-0.003) - beforeRenderModule mod_menu_acordeon (Gestión)
Application 4.305 seconds (+0.128); 10.73 MB (+0.012) - afterRenderModule mod_menu_acordeon (Gestión)
Application 4.309 seconds (+0.004); 10.81 MB (+0.073) - beforeRenderModule mod_calendarfilter (Calendario)
Application 4.391 seconds (+0.083); 11.49 MB (+0.679) - afterRenderModule mod_calendarfilter (Calendario)
Application 4.391 seconds (+0.000); 11.47 MB (-0.012) - beforeRenderModule mod_menu (Mensajes)
Application 4.450 seconds (+0.058); 11.51 MB (+0.032) - afterRenderModule mod_menu (Mensajes)
Application 4.450 seconds (+0.000); 11.50 MB (-0.002) - beforeRenderModule mod_jomsocial_groups_extended_16 (Mis grupos)
Application 4.503 seconds (+0.053); 11.57 MB (+0.063) - afterRenderModule mod_jomsocial_groups_extended_16 (Mis grupos)
Application 4.503 seconds (+0.000); 11.55 MB (-0.021) - beforeRenderModule mod_onlineusers (Usuarios online)
Application 4.663 seconds (+0.160); 11.82 MB (+0.279) - afterRenderModule mod_onlineusers (Usuarios online)
Application 4.663 seconds (+0.000); 11.82 MB (-0.003) - beforeRenderModule mod_joomdle_my_grades (Mis calificaciones)
Application 4.712 seconds (+0.050); 11.83 MB (+0.006) - afterRenderModule mod_joomdle_my_grades (Mis calificaciones)
Application 4.716 seconds (+0.003); 11.85 MB (+0.028) - beforeRenderModule mod_languages (Idioma)
Application 4.755 seconds (+0.039); 12.01 MB (+0.153) - afterRenderModule mod_languages (Idioma)
Application 4.755 seconds (+0.000); 12.01 MB (-0.003) - beforeRenderModule mod_search (Buscador)
Application 4.776 seconds (+0.021); 12.02 MB (+0.017) - afterRenderModule mod_search (Buscador)
Application 4.776 seconds (+0.000); 12.02 MB (-0.006) - beforeRenderModule mod_qalerts (User Info)
Application 5.542 seconds (+0.766); 13.57 MB (+1.553) - afterRenderModule mod_qalerts (User Info)
Application 5.543 seconds (+0.001); 13.59 MB (+0.020) - beforeRenderModule mod_js_flexslider (slider top)
Application 5.597 seconds (+0.055); 13.63 MB (+0.040) - afterRenderModule mod_js_flexslider (slider top)
Application 5.598 seconds (+0.001); 13.60 MB (-0.024) - beforeRenderModule mod_languages (posidioma-movil)
Application 5.640 seconds (+0.042); 13.61 MB (+0.005) - afterRenderModule mod_languages (posidioma-movil)
Application 6.846 seconds (+1.206); 13.88 MB (+0.274) - afterRender
```

Also I created a SQL debug with times, and all queries takes only 0.03 seconds, so I think is not a SQL problem.

Answer (score 0):

depends on where you exactly running this debug.

If in content (article), try to remove all article plugins and test it again.

If in other site or in content, try to unpublish all possible system plugins and test it again.

When you disable the system plugins, the loading should be faster, then enabling the plugins (system or content if article is displayed) step by step you will discover which plugin's loading takes the time.

Try to set other template too, maybe you get other loading outcomes too.

Jan